# FetchXML. The entered and stored passwords do not match

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml, windows-live-id

My CRM updated, and since then my custom reporting tool  hasnt been working.

It uses PHP and the EntityUtils provided in examples.  The issue is that I can authenticate with a LiveID but when I use CURL to get the soap response it gives a response of:

```
S:Senderwst:FailedAuthenticationAuthentication Failure0x800488210x80041012The entered and stored passwords do not match.
```

I've made sure that the email/password is correct by logging in, and verified that all URLs are correct.

Comment: in your code do you have a line like this one?
`curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 3);`

Comment: exactly like that, yes

Comment: Took it out.  Works again, you're my hero; could you explain why this would break it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: the solution was found by Andrew Campey on Dynamics Community Forum ([link](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/145616.aspx))

SSL v3.0 has been removed from Dynamics CRM due to the `Poodle` vulnerability.
Non .NET clients need to handle most of the authentication process, including the SSL version.

The solution is to change the SSL version inside the curl request, from 3 to 4:

```
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
```